# Help with increasing partition size

Tags: partitioning, gparted

First off, I'm still new to linux so I apologize ahead of time for my ignorance.  So as the title indicates I need help with resizing a partition.  To be specific, I need to add more space to the sda2 partition which is my main folder for Ubuntu. (see picture below)  After cloning my old ssd (64G) to this new ssd (240G) I allocated the extra space to the wrong partition during the cloning process.  So now I need to get most of the space from the sda3 (Linux-swap) partition and add it to sda2.  I already have Gparted on a bootable USB drive to make the changes, but I just don't know how to go about it.  Hoping someone can help me out.
Thanks.

[Picture of Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzb6h.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since You need to resize `sda3` and then move the free space next to `sda2` to make `sda2` bigger, you're going to have to move partitions around. This can cause problems, but I did it a few times with no real issues.

I did it by resizing my partition from the left to give free space on the left, but that meant for me that I had to move a ~800GB partition, including the free space. That took forever.

You have smaller partitions, but I think the following would be the quickest, easiest and safest way.

- Start out by downsizing `sda3` so that the free space following is the amount of space you want to add to `sda2`.
- Then, you'll have to move `sda3` over so the free space is on the left of `sda3` and the right of `sda2`.
- Resize `sda2` to take up that free space.
- Apply the operation. (It's going to take some time, but since you have an SSD and small partitions, I'd estimate an ETA of less than 2 hours.)

Hopefully, you won't have any problems. Just definitely do this from a LiveCD or Gparted CD and not from an OS booted on the drive.

If you need any more help, just comment.

Comment: This did the trick. It took all of 10 seconds to do the partition. Thank you.